# Used backbone, node and mySQL for building example. When refreshing detail page, it doesn't render

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I've built a classic example from a book displaying a list of books with informations like title, publication date, author, and keywords. It's an enhancement taken from Addy Osmani's book example. So each item has a delete and detail button. And at the top of the page, above the book list, there is a form to add books. Please don't use the form cause i have no validation implemented. Here's the URL: http://fubaritico-mysql.jit.su/

The problem is when I click on the detail button of an item, I go to the detail state properly with an URL like http://fubaritico-mysql.jit.su/api/books/1. But when I refresh the page, I get a JSON response displayed instead of the same content. I don't know how to handle this. Itried parsing but it's not the way.

I had the same problem with all the things I tried whatever way I used (node-mongoDB, node-MySQL, localStorage).

See: "Introduction to Backbone.js Part 2 - Server-side" on Youtube. It's the first tutorial I tried and it was already the same problem. At the end of the video, Michael Yagudaev explained what to do very briefly but I just didn't get it.

I get a JSON response displayed when calling GET "/dir/item/0".

Thanks for your help or advices

Stefcot

---

My question is how do you proceed when you remove the hash from the URL.
Michael Yagudaev told about overriding Backbone.sync to do the job.
He also said it could a lot of job and that wont be worthwhile though.
You have to create an API of your own and link it to Backbone.sync.
Of course I guess you have to do some programming for each CRUD action.

Below is a template taken from Addy Osmany's book for a lead on how to achieve that
when MyAPI is an API of your own:

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
function success(result) {
    // Handle successful results from MyAPI
    if (options.success) {
        options.success(result);
    }
}
function error(result) {
    // Handle error results from MyAPI
    if (options.error) {
        options.error(result);
    }
}

options || (options = {});

switch (method) {
    case 'create':
        return MyAPI.create(model, success, error);
    case 'update':
        return MyAPI.update(model, success, error);
    case 'patch':
        return MyAPI.patch(model, success, error);
    case 'delete':
        return MyAPI.destroy(model, success, error);
    case 'read':
        if (model.attributes[model.idAttribute]) {
            return MyAPI.find(model, success, error);
        } else {
            return MyAPI.findAll(model, success, error);
        }
}};
```

Again, a great thanks and thanks for further clarification about this.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using express and an RESTful API interface

Comment: Seems to me that the problem is inside backbone router. Could you test the same thing but without push state?

Comment: Indeed it works with the hash left on the URL, I made the test very quickly and no JSON, I tested some other tuts I made locally and it works all the way. What doesn't work on refresh here is my part for corrections in my router, it's not about Backbone. A great thanks to you. I checked others sites I like, and well, there is a hash too. Before closing this issue, I have one question left I add on my ticket above.